# Fuseki 2 & Cross Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability

Tags: xss, fuseki

I'm working with Apache Fuseki 2.3.1. on Linux RedHat as a standalone server:

```
>> java -Xmx16384M -jar fuseki-server.jar --port=8080 --loc=/space/tdb /ds
```

The safety tests team has raised an anomaly of Cross Site Scripting (XSS). 
Does anyone know how to prevent this issue?

Comment: For example, it's possible to write on:
http://myurl/dataset.html

a query like:

SELECT "<script>alert(document.domain)</script>"
WHERE {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
LIMIT 25 

thath show a pop-up whith hostname.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by Jena/Fuseki team and will be released on next version of Fuseki (2.4.0).
See:

[Cross Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability on Fuseki 2.3.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1123)